# Regular expression must start with a letter and ends with digits in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract a string pattern using python:

1. must start with capital letter 'C'
2. middle part can contain /
3. must ends with one or two digits

example strings:

```
193 skol C/12
334 skol C/6
577 skol C12
345 skol C6
```

expected matching results will be:

```
C/12
C/6
C12
C6
```

This is what my regular expression looks like:

```
df['a'].str.extract('^[C]\/?\d{1,2}$')
```

However, it doesn't generate the expected results.I tried to add "[ ]" in the regular expression, but it still doesn't work :( Can anyone please give me some suggestions?  Thanks so much!

Comment: You may use: `r'\bC/?\d{1,2}\b'`

Comment: It looks like you're also attempting to match start-of-line and end-of-line. But none of your start-of-line positions occur directly before "C". Perhaps try removing ^ and $ from your match?

Comment: @depwl9992 Thanks for your suggestion, it works!

Comment: @QianLi Please dont forget to mark one of the answers as the solution if your question is answered. If you'd like to give depwl9992 credit you can ask them to make their comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
C\/?\d{1,2}
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2hMgWz/2)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\C(\/|)\d{1,2}$
```

`\C` - Catch literal upper C 
`(/\|)` - Catch literal `/` or none (pipe simbol with no match after)
`\d{1,2}$` - Catch on or two numbers at end

Code:

```
df['a'].str.extract(r'\C(\/|)\d{1,2}$')
```

Comment: Why backslash escape the `C` and why not use just `\/?` instead of pipe?

Comment: because there's some matches then need to catch backslash, or not, such as `C6` `C\12`. So, the empty group with empty pipe will get a backslash or none.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd    
a = pd.Series(['193 skol C/12','334 skol C/6','577 skol C12','345 skol C6'])

a.str.extract('(C\/?\d+)')
```

> ```
> 0    C/12
> 1     C/6
> 2     C12
> 3      C6
> ```

**Why it works:**

( Capturing group #1. Groups multiple tokens together and creates a capture group for extracting a substring or using a backreference.

C Character. Matches a "C" character (char code 67).

/ Escaped character. Matches a "/" character (char code 47).

? Optional. Match between 0 and 1 of the preceding token.

\d Digit. Matches any digit character (0-9).

+ Plus. Match 1 or more of the preceding token.

)